# What does a JSON array look like in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have created a simple `json` string to decode into a `data` array, but I am very confused about how to iterate through the array once it is decoded:

```
<?php
    $json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

    $data = json_decode($json, true);

    for ($j = 0; $j < count($data); $j++) {
        echo "$j: $data[$j]<br>";
    }
?>
```

I can't seem to get this code to work because it is saying that every offset is undefined, so I think the trouble stems from my understanding of what an array looks like once it has been decoded.

When I do a `var_dump(json_decode($json, true))`, I get this result:

```
array (size=5)
  'a' => int 1
  'b' => int 2
  'c' => int 3
  'd' => int 4
  'e' => int 5
```

So what does this mean exactly? Are the array `indexes` 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', and 'e' respectively? If so, then how can I iterate through each of these to print out all of their values?

Comment: With `foreach`. How did you ever get to `json_decode` without learning `foreach` in the process?

Comment: You have an associative array, not a numerical array. Learn more about arrays in the PHP documentation: http://us2.php.net//manual/en/language.types.array.php . *"What does a JSON array look like in PHP?"* JSON looks the same everywhere. `[1,2,3]` is an array, `{"foo": "bar"}` is an object.

Comment: `$i=0;foreach($data as $item){ echo "$i: $item</br>";$i++;}`

Comment: not to forget: http://php.net/array_keys

Comment: Thanks everyone. I think I have a better understanding now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays in PHP are not the same as arrays in JavaScript (or Json). However, what you're looking at here:

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

Is not actually a Json array, but a Json object. `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `e` are properties of that object (which are a bit like indexes in a PHP array).

To iterate through the properties of this object, you can use a `foreach` loop:

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value<br>";
}
```